# Issue appending to headers object after axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, append, axios

So my initial request, getBookingSessionId grabs an id that needs to be passed into my headers object inside my axios.create() method so it can be used inside my next request.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { strings } from '../strings';

class CorasApi {
  constructor() {
    const url = 'https://sandbox.coras.io';
    this.bookingSessionId = null;
```

this creates an instance of axios and holds my headers

```
      this.request = axios.create({
      baseURL: url,
      headers: {
        'Coras-Distributor': strings.coras.distributorId,
        'Content-Type': strings.coras.contentType,
      }
    });
  }


 getBookingSessionId = () => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.request
    .post('/booking-session/', null, null, {})
    .then(res => {
      //   debugger;
      resolve(res);
```

Here i'm trying to append the result of my request to my headers object

```
      this.bookingSessionId = res.data['booking-session'];
      this.request.headers.append('Booking-Session', this.bookingSessionId);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
};
```

this is the next request that requires the 'Booking-Session' header

```
 async getShows() {
  await this.getBookingSessionId();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.request
    .get('/events/', null, {})
    .then(res => resolve(res))
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults), you can alter the defaults after the instance has been created.

```
getBookingSessionId = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.request
       .post('/booking-session/', null, null, {})
       .then(res => {
         resolve(res);
         this.bookingSessionId = res.data['booking-session'];
         // this.request.headers.append('Booking-Session', this.bookingSessionId); 
         this.request.defaults.headers.common['Booking-Session'] = this.bookingSessionId; // replace the line above with this
       })
       .catch(err => {
         reject(err);
       });
   });
 };
```

Comment: Could you expand a little on this answer, e.g. showing where to add this call into the code in the question, and why it would work?